# error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] Found a dependency cycle

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2

Can any one tell me why this error is showing. I tried a lot some stackoverflow post, but can not identify. Am struggling with this error for whole day. before dagger 2.11 it was working fine. after updating to 2.11 is the error.

```
        E:\studio projects\MVP-Login\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\anbu\mvpkotlin\di\component\AppComponent.java:8: error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] Found a dependency cycle:
public abstract interface AppComponent {
            ^
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.data.network.NccApi is injected at
      com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.di.modules.AppModules.provideAPI$app_debug(apiManager)
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.data.network.NccApi is injected at
      com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.interactor.AccountInteractor.<init>(…, api)
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.interactor.AccountInteractor is injected at
      com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.AccountModule.provideAccountInteractor$app_debug(accountInteractor)
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.interactor.AccountInteractorContract is injected at
      com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.presenter.AccountPresenter.<init>(interactor, …)
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.presenter.AccountPresenter<com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.view.AccountViewContract,com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.interactor.AccountInteractorContract> is injected at
      com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.AccountModule.provideAccountPresenter$app_debug(accountPresenter)
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.presenter.AccountPresenterContract<com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.view.AccountViewContract,com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.interactor.AccountInteractorContract> is injected at
      com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.view.AccountActivity.presenter
  com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.ui.accounts.view.AccountActivity is injected at
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

Here is my AppComponent class I have added in my project. It is not exactly abstract as the error shows.

```
    @Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AndroidInjectionModule::class), (ActivityBuilder::class),
    (AppModules::class)])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: MyApplication)

}
```

And here is Application Module class I have added in my project.

```
@Module
class AppModules {

@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideContext(application: Application): Context = application

@Provides
@PreferenceInfo
internal fun providePrefName(): String = AppConstants.PREF_NAME

@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun providePreference(prefManager: PrefManager): 
PrefManagerContract = prefManager

@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideAppDatabase(context: Context): NccDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, NccDatabase::class.java, "****")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()

@Provides
internal fun provideCompositeDisposable(): CompositeDisposable = 
CompositeDisposable()

@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideAPI(apiManager: NccApi): NccApi = apiManager

@Provides
internal fun provideSchedulerProvider(): SchedulerProvider = 
SchedulerProvider()

/*@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun providerTokenManager(): TokenManager = TokenManager()*/
```

This is my AccountModule class

```
            @Module
    class AccountModule {

        @Provides
        internal fun provideAccountInteractor(accountInteractor: AccountInteractor): AccountInteractorContract = accountInteractor

        @Provides
        internal fun provideAccountPresenter(accountPresenter: AccountPresenter<AccountViewContract, AccountInteractorContract>)
                : AccountPresenterContract<AccountViewContract, AccountInteractorContract> = accountPresenter
    }
```

Here is my Retrofit web services interface

```
public interface NccApi {

        Observable<Profile> getProfile(@Url String url, @Header("authorization") String auth);

        @POST
        Call<SigninResponseModel> refreshToken(@Url String url, @Header("authorization") String auth, @Body RefreshTokenRequest body);
    }
```

Here is my retrofit module class

```
        @Module
    class RetrofitModule(internal var mBaseUrl: String) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideInterceptor(): okhttp3.Interceptor {
        val interceptorAPI = Interceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            var request: Request? = null
            try {
                request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build()
            } catch (authFailureError: Exception) {
                authFailureError.printStackTrace()
            }

            val response = chain.proceed(request)

            response
        }
        return interceptorAPI
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideGson(): Gson {
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        return gsonBuilder.create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptor: Interceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        okHttpBuilder.interceptors().add(interceptor)
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        okHttpBuilder.interceptors().add(logging)
        val client = okHttpBuilder.build()
        return client
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
        return retrofit
    }
    }
```

Here is my Application class

```
class MyApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit internal var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector() = activityDispatchingAndroidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .appmodule(AppModules())
                .retrofitModule(RetrofitModule(""))
                .build()
                .inject(this)

    }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your modules and components to see how you configured dagger

Comment: I never knew you could have an abstract interface...learned something new

Comment: I have added my code @Levi.

Comment: It is not abstract check my code above @ZUNJAE

Comment: You need to post AccountModule as well

Comment: added account module class @LeviAlbuquerque

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dependency cycle is here:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideAPI(apiManager: NccApi): NccApi = apiManager
```

You're dependening on the apiManager to provide an apiManager. You should have something like this in here:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideAPI(): NccApi = NccApi()
```

The above is just an example, the point is that you need to instantiate your api to provide it. Or, if you have an interface that your apiManager implements you should return that from the provide method, so you request an actual object and returns the interface. Bu requesting an actual object and returning it you doing the dependency cycle right there.

Comment: but that is my web service interface for Retrofit networking. I can not create object for Interface...Rit?... check web service class added above...

Comment: don't you have a wrapper for iitializing the retrofit interface? Normally one has a class where they do `retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);` and that's the class that it's normally provided by dagger

Comment: Yes I forget that. Thanks for remembering me. Now I removed NccApi injection in presenter constructor instead I injected Retrofit instance all places in presenter. After that I will call retrofit.create(NccApi.class);

Comment: But still the problem persist. Don't know why

Comment: Ok, suppose your api wrapper is called RetrofitConfig, you should be doing this : internal fun provideAPI(): RetrofitConfig = RetrofitConfig(), are you doing this?

Comment: No, instead of wrapper I directly returned Retrofit instance using separate provider. Like  internal fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit{
///retrofit config and return
}

Comment: now I got different error. 
error: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [com.example.anbu.mvpkotlin.data.network.RetrofitModule]
    public static abstract interface Builder {
                           ^

Comment: hope soon will fix the issue. can you help some more time

Comment: You've got a Retrofit Module? Can I see it?

Comment: added Retrofit module and Application class

Comment: I have added 
fun retrofitModule(retrofitModule: RetrofitModule): Builder
in my AppComponet as a setter, it is fixed. You are really awesome. I have forget to create wrapper for Interface class. That is the main entry point to solve this issue. Thanks Man #Levi